# take sum of ints preserving specific information

Tags: python

I have a list of ints

```
list = [25, 50, 70, 32, 10, 20, 50, 40, 30]
```

And I would like to sum up the ints (from left to right) if their sum is smaller than 99. Lets say I write this output to a list, than this list should look like this:

```
           #75 because 25+50 = 70. 25+50+70 would be > 99
new_list = [75, 70, 62, 90, 30]
               #70 because 70+32 > 99
                   #62 because 32+10+20 = 62. 32+10+20+50 would be > 99
```

But that is not all. I want to save the ints the sum was made from as well. So what I actually want to have is a data structure that looks like this:

```
list0 = [ [(25,50),75], [(70),70], [(32, 10, 20),62], [(50, 40),90], [(30),30] ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds a lot like the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), except that you just want to try it in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate list to track your numbers:

```
results = []
result = []
for num in inputlist:
    if sum(result) + num < 100:
        result.append(num)
    else:
        results.append([tuple(result), sum(result)])
        result = [num]
if result:
    results.append([tuple(result), sum(result)])
```

For your sample input, this produces:

```
[[(25, 50), 75], [(70,), 70], [(32, 10, 20), 62], [(50, 40), 90], [(30,), 30]]
```

Comment: I tested your code with the list `[19, 73, 28, 77]` and it gave `[[(19, 73), 92], [(28,), 28]]`. The last int is lost :>

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterator fo this:

```
l = [25, 50, 70, 32, 10, 20, 50, 40, 30]

def sum_iter(lst):
    s = 0
    t = tuple()
    for i in lst:
       if s + i <= 99:
          s += i
          t += (i,)
       else:
           yield t, s
           s = i
           t = (i,)
    else:
       yield t, s


res = [[t, s] for t, s in sum_iter(l)]
```

On your data result is:

```
[[(25, 50), 75], [(70,), 70], [(32, 10, 20), 62], [(50, 40), 90], [(30,), 30]]
```